# Two loaders on a screen - good interaction pattern?

Tags: loading, lazy-loading

Recently, I noticed a micro-interaction on **LinkedIn** where there were **2 loaders** on the same page - **different in size and color**. They were probably for loading different types of content. Is this a good UX pattern?

**How did I reach this state:**
I opened the notifications tab and pulled down to refresh feed before notifications were fully loaded.

*Maybe this was not an intended interaction, and happened because of 2 types of content loading simultaneously.*
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Twitter has that, too - a spinner for each region that is still loading.

[image: Twitter screen with three loaders]

In Twitter's case, that's a good pattern, because it's used on live content regions, and helps the user know that something dynamic is being loaded. The regions impart a sense of what content the user might expect. Navigation and other static elements don't use a loader.

On the example you posted, the spinners are confusing because you don't see clearly-defined regions, and nothing indicates what's loading. As you mentioned, they are different sizes and colors, which unintentionally attracts attention and might increase mental load.

So, I think having multiple loaders on a page can be good UX, when done correctly. The example you posted needs a little more baking.